# Paragraphs + selectlist based bg-color

Tags: theming, paragraphs

I have a selectlist-field based bg-colors:

- yellow
- black
- blue

I added this to paragraph bundle called 'Hero'. Now i got selectlist-field on this paragraph bundle. How do I print that yellow to paragraphs-item template? I tried it few times but it always returned 1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a preprocess hook to add a class / set a style to the paragraph based on the field content.

Here's some sample code from one of my sites that uses this.  The options for bg_color field are like:  "Ghost Gray" => "eeeeee" and the like.  The paragraph type is colorsection.

```
function my_module_preprocess_paragraph__colorsection(&$variables) {
  if (!$variables['paragraph']->field_bg_color->isEmpty()) {
    $variables['attributes']['style'][] = 'background: #'.$variables['paragraph']->field_bg_color->value.';';
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'bg-'.$variables['paragraph']->field_bg_color->value;
  }
}
```